# In Linux, XSI/System-V IPC mechanisms are outdated?

Tags: linux, posix, ipc, sysv

Is the XSI/System V IPC is outdated since we have POSIX IPC mechanisms available in Linux?

What kind of IPC (Sysv/Posix/other) is recommended for newer programs ?

Comment: I've seen mainly POSIX and CORBA used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIX for basics and dbus for “convoluted” :) things.

CORBA, humm, the only executables depending on it for me are libgnome-2.so and libreoffice, which is a whole lot less than dbus.

Comment: It seems all are favoring POSIX, CORBA, DBUS etc . So the old SystemV APIs (msgget,msgsnd ,semget, shmget.....) are slowly getting out of use?